# How to wrap rows to multiple lines in free jqgrid or other table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jqgrid, html-table, free-jqgrid

In narrow screen mobile devices jqgrid table should wrapped into multiple lines.
For example, table in wider screen

```
OrderNo  Date       Customer                 Sum 
001     12.7.2915   OKSoft Incorporated      12000.00
002     14.7.2015   Rott Corporated          13444.54
```

In mobile should appear as

```
OrderNo  Date       
Customer   
Sum 
-------------------
001     12.7.2915   
OKSoft Incorporated
12000.00
-------------------
002     14.7.2015   
Rott Corporated
13444.54
```

How force jqgrid to wrap lines?
I havent found any option for this.

Or is there any other free grid which has such adaptive layout ?

Bootstrap, jquery, jquery-ui, ASP.NET MVC4 are used

Comment: I don't think that wrapping of rows could be the solution for mobile devices. HTML `<table>` will be not wrapped. I personally like more the approach which you can see in the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/7/. If you would resize the window on the demo then the last column `ComboDuration` will be hidden or shown dynamically depend on the resolution of the outer container.

Comment: If jqgrid table cannot wrapped how to force number of columns from jqgrid colmodel to appear in single cell in multiple lines ?

Comment: What I mean is not a restriction of jqGrid table. It's restriction of HTML `<tr>` and `<table>` element.

Comment: One have to use `<div>` elements for example instead of HTML tables. By the way I personally would find wrapped information from your question very bad. It displays a mix of numbers and the user will have to interpret which number corresponds to which field. I think that the user will have to spend really many time to read such information. Good page design allows the user to find the information really quickly.

Comment: Visit card also shows such information and is considered very readable. How to create custom jqgrid formatter which puts multiple fields into single jqgrid cell using something like `display: inline-blok for them`? If table contains one column this column can wrapped.